# yearmon subsetting with xts returns 'incorrect' range. why?

Tags: r, date, xts

When subsetting an xts yearmon object using date strings I don't get the dates I ask for.  The returned row(s) are offset forward by one month. Why?  Thanks!

```
# create a two year series of monthly data
asyearmon<-as.xts(1:24,as.yearmon('2012-01')+(0:23)/12)
asyearmon['201206',]
#asking for June returns July
#         [,1]
#Jul 2012    7
asyearmon['201206/201212',]
#asking for the rest of 2012 includes Jan 2013
#         [,1]
#Jul 2012    7
#Aug 2012    8
#Sep 2012    9
#Oct 2012   10
#Nov 2012   11
#Dec 2012   12
#Jan 2013   13
```